# Is there any way to NDEF format NFC tag in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My question is how can I NDEF format the empty NFC tag in Flutter? Currently, I'm using 3rd party SDK nfc_in_flutter, but it only supports already NDEF formatted tags. Any ideas how to solve that?

Here is my code.

```
NDEFMessage newMessage = NDEFMessage.withRecords([
  NDEFRecord.uri(path),
]);

Stream<NDEFTag> stream = NFC.writeNDEF(newMessage, once: true);
stream.listen((NDEFTag tag) {
  showNotification(context, 'NFC Tag was activated.');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NFC SDK that I mentioned: https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter